# send images with ajax and django

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I try to send images from `<input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="image/*" multiple>` without sending al the form. I found many post which explain this so I do this

urls.py

```
url(r'^images/', 'app.views.images', name='images'),
```

view.py

```
def images(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('hello')
```

jquery

```
$("#file").change(function (){
    try{
        var formdata = new FormData();
        var files = $('#file')[0].files;
        formdata.append('file',files);
        jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "images/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                         // if all is well
                         // play the audio file
                    }
                });
        }
    catch(err){
        alert(err.message);
        }
});
```

But this gives me `"POST /images/ HTTP/1.1" 403` error

I did diferent test and I think the error is the `data: formdata` part

Comment: Do you have a middleware that could be throwing the 403?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either send the `csrf_token` in the ajax request.

```
formdata["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = '{{ csrf_token }}';  //add csrf token to the reauest data
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "images/",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (result) {
        // if all is well
        // play the audio file
    }
});
```

Or use [@csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) on the your view.

```
#views.py

@csrf_exempt
def images(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('hello')
```

Comment: `formdata["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = '{{ csrf_token }}';` this way doesn´t works but with `@csrf_exempt` works fine, thank you